# How to reuse primary key Ids which has been rolled-backed by a transaction

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have an employee table. When persisting an Employee object, due to business logic if some subsequent call fails I roll back the transaction using the @transactional annotation in spring boot.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "employee_generator")
    private Long id;
}
```

When it rolls back it does not use the autogenerated ID again.
For example, if the generated id is 1, and it rolls back; it never uses the id 1 again for subsequent save calls. Therefore I have huge gaps in the auto-generated id.
Like 2, 10, 20 etc.

I would like to have a continuous value for the auto-generated id. How can I do this in hibernate and Postgres sql.

Comment: An identifier exists just to identify a record. When you start giving this identifier any (!) other meaning, you get into trouble. Big trouble. Start using UUID's to avoid this. Or don't try to give this numbered id any other meaning and find a proper solution for your business logic. Record 13, 28474 or 877845649, just 3 different records.

Comment: You can look at the technique described in [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/#gapless-sequence), but be warned that gapless sequences are quite bad for performance.

Comment: Get rid of having a *continuous value for the auto-generated id*  idea. Read the first sentence in  @LaurenzAlbe's article, then read it again, and again until you are convinced.  Gaps are normal and **desirable**. Consider a multi user environment. You get id 2 while another user gets id 3. Now the other user finishes successfully but your attempt then gets rolled back and resets the generator. So who will be the lucky one that gets a duplicate key violation when id 3 is again generated from the auto sequence? A *legal requirement* is only time  a gap-less sequence is warranted. (imho)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys :) , I will switch to a UUID-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a sequenceGenerator:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="employee_generator", sequenceName="employee_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="employee_generator")
    private Long id;
}
```

Then add seq to DB:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE employee_seq START 1;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).